# how to pass url in request through upstream proxy using Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

How to pass our client request through Authorized upstream proxy to specific web address ?

I have to enter username/password to connect an upstream proxy and then open some web page in my browser (for example jj.com) in HTTP and HTTPS protocol (I can set that in Firefox manual proxy options).
So I want make a way to get access for other client to open jj.com whitout need to know and enter username/password and open web page (like jj.com) in her/his browser through NginX.

```
 +--------------------+                      +---------------------+
 |                    |                      | upstramProxy:9090   |       +----------+
 | Client browser     |                      | user:user-003       |+----->| jj.com   |
 |                    |                      | pass:123456         |<------+----------+
 +--------------------+                      +---------------------+
     |  ^ (myProxyService.com:8080/pr?url=jj.com)   |  ^
     |  |                                           |  |
     |  |                                           |  |
     |  |                                +---------------------+
     |  +--------------------------------| myProxyService.com  |
     |                                   | NginX in myServer   |
     +---------------------------------->| Listen to 8080      |
                                         +---------------------+
```

Is it possible ?
If there is any other approach I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple java web application in witch java send all request through third party proxy named : myProxyServer

```
 public static void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        System.out.println(req.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println(req.getRequestURL());
        jjTools.ShowAllParameter(req);
        final BasicCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("thirdpartyProxy.com", 8080),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "passss".toCharArray())
        );
        try (final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build()) {
            
            final HttpHost target = new HttpHost("https", "www.targetwebSite.com", 443);
            final HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("http", "thirdpartyProxy.com", 8080);
            final RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setProxy(proxy)
                    .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
                    .build();                                        
            final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(req.getRequestURI().replaceFirst("/My_Proxy/", "/"));                
            httpget.setConfig(config);                

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getMethod() + " " + httpget.getUri()
                    + " via " + proxy);

            try (final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget)) {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                resp.setContentType(response.getHeader("Content-Type").toString());
                System.out.println(response.getHeader("Content-Type").toString());
                System.out.println(response.getCode() + " " + response.getReasonPhrase());
                out.print(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())+"<scipt>alert");
            }
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Listener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Then you have to config nginX.conf like the code below:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name         targetwebSite.localhost;
    location / {
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/My_Proxy/;
    }
```

}

And for result it will be working for all page with its CSS and JavaScript files in

> http : / / targetwebSite.localhost /

address

note: It have some problem with cookie and accept cookie policies in browser

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_httpclient/apache_httpclient_using_proxy.htm